# Extra form on ModelFormSet

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

For my Django project, I am rendering the model formset `election_formset = modelformset_factory(Election, exclude=('Complete',), formset=BaseElectionFormSet)` in my template:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-body w-75 mx-auto'>

                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                        <p>Name<br>{{form.Name}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                        <p>Videos<br>{{form.FlipGrid}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-12 text-center'>
                        <p>Description<br>{{form.Description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                        <p>Allow registration: {{form.CandidateReg}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                        <p>Allow voting: {{form.VotingOpen}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

When the formset renders, an extra, blank form is shown at the end of the forms. I only want forms to show that are instances of existing records. Why is there an extra blank formset and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
election_formset = modelformset_factory(
    Election,
    exclude=('Complete',),
    formset=BaseElectionFormSet,
    extra=0
)
```

The `extra` keyword defaults to 1 otherwise (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/models/#modelformset-factory)):

```
def modelformset_factory(model, form=ModelForm, formfield_callback=None,
                         formset=BaseModelFormSet, extra=1, can_delete=False,
                         can_order=False, max_num=None, fields=None, exclude=None,
                         widgets=None, validate_max=False, localized_fields=None,
                         labels=None, help_texts=None, error_messages=None,
                         min_num=None, validate_min=False, field_classes=None):
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`max_num`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#limiting-the-maximum-number-of-forms) parameter to limit exta if there are some initial data in formset:

```
election_formset = modelformset_factory(Election, exclude=('Complete',), formset=BaseElectionFormSet, max_num=1)
```

From the docs:

> If the number of items in the initial data exceeds max_num, all initial data forms will be displayed regardless of the value of max_num and no extra forms will be displayed.